# XmlDocument::Save() appends the xml in file

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument

I want to keep a single XmlDocument object in a class and let methods make changes to it and save it.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Diary.xml", 
       FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(fs);

    // ... make some changes here

    xmlDoc.Save(fs);
}
```

The above code makes two copies of the xml structure inside the file.

Comment: Why are you using the FileStream when you can specify the filepath for Load?  I *think* the default behavior for file access is what you have specified.

Comment: The XML file is shared among different modules that read it (not write). I want to open/read and lock for writing in this module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
fs.SetLength(0);
```

before Save call

Comment: @IanR.O'Brien This is because, he is using the same filestream to load the file (therefore after the load the position is at the end of the file. But what you want to do, is to truncate what's already in the stream before writing out the XML again.

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
fs.Position = 0;
```

before the Save call.

Comment: I tried that but it has a very wierd behavior. Some of the data gets overwritten and the whole file is now not a valid XML file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit strange that fs.Position from Foole's solution didn't work.

An equivalent would be

```
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Alternatively

instead of using the same filestream:

```
            //OrigPath is the path you're using for the FileReader

            System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(OrigPath);
            xmlDoc.Save(writer);
            writer.Close();
```

Comment: It will not work, because if the original XML file is 1000 chars long, and after changing the xmldocument it contains only 600 chars left, you will be left with 400 chars at the end of the correct XML file which do not get deleted. Hence why the validation error e.g.
original 
<test><book1></book1></test>

you change xmldocument to <test><a></a></test>

you will end up with
<test><a></a></test>></test>

Notice the unnecessary "></test>" at the end

Comment: Right!! UP for @LnDCobra's comment

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively even this would work...

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument( );
        xmlDoc.Load( @"D:\Diary.xml" );

        //.... make some changes here
        XmlText node = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode( "test" );
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild( node );

        xmlDoc.Save( @"D:\Diary.xml" );
```

Comment: Well, this might work but I think it will be much more efficient to just set the length to zero and call Save

Comment: This won't work because to file will be i  use at that time so i can't never save the file..